# Display Loading Circle During In-App Purchase Server Callback

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to show the loading circle during the user's wait time while he has pressed the purchase button and in the background, some processing running with the device on Play Store or Apple Store server related to transaction authentication.

Especially this time is more when you purchase something on an iOS device so I want to give some indication that the user has to wait for some time.

This code I was using to implement in-app purchase within the game:
[Unity IAP](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/unity-iap#)

All the code is related to server callback so I don't know where to place code related to show and hide loading circle.
I hope you got my point in this so please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

When you call any of your BuyWhatever methods, like `BuyProductID`, you can trigger a UI element (your loading circle) to pop-up and start spinning arround, when your purchase finish and the callback `PurchaseProcessingResult` is called, stop and hide the loading circle.